# How can one visualize a homomorphic mapping.

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, soft-question, intuition

It has been a year or so studying Group theory and Ring theory. Funnily enough, this is the part where i am able to solve most of the questions of the book quite easily,  yet not fully understanding what a homomorphic map really is. Though, i find it much easier to visualize an isomorphic map.

I know the definition. But I'd like to understand it with a visual approach. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Curious: How do you visualize an isomorphism?

Comment: homomorphisms preserves structure of group/ring.

Comment: @313: i read it somewhere. Would you please elaborate?

Comment: @Kaj: The element and its image behave similarly in their respective groups. The basic structure of the two groups is the same as said by 313. The structure part makes sense for isomorphism, but i am not able to understand it in the case of homomorphism.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242348/intuition-on-group-homomorphisms

Comment: if you draw a table that show the "." of group then a homomorphism preserves structure on that table. at the row "a" and column "b" you have the element "ab". under homomorphism "f", at the row "f(a)" and column "f(b)" you have the element "f(ab)"

Comment: @313: Makes much more sense now..Thank you..

Comment: you are welcome.

Comment: I think the main difficulty with answering your question is that we do not know what your mental picture of a group or a ring is. And, of course, you may well have multiple perspectives--in my case, if I am given an arbitrary ring $R$, I view it as a black box and shift attention to its modules, while I almost always imagine the internal structure of $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @Karl: I know, that's hard to answer for you. I wanted to know about how others visualize it. In the link posted above by Prahlad, the person who answered cleared my doubts and gave me a new perspective. Try reading it. You'll be amazed. :)

Comment: (I speak purely from a ring theorist's perspective) It's a good answer, but it ignores some important things that a ring homomorphisms capture. The first thing to come to mind is that you can pass ideals between rings via homomorphisms (indeed in both directions), and this motion is certainly not the same as approximation.

Comment: since there are many comments and no answer to this good question, I write my comments as an answer

Comment: Groups really aren't visual objects...

Comment: Perhaps look on p. 38 of the following article: http://issuu.com/thedeltaepsilon/docs/de7 . It "illustrates" the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: Do you understand what an isomorphism is? How about a quotient group? If so then combine them.

Comment: You point towards the first isomorphism theorem? I know that, but that doesn't solve the intuition thing that I'm looking for. I might be sounding very lame but that's how it is. :(

Comment: In my opinion, reading [1] may be of great help.  [1] Nathan Carter, *Visual Group Theory*, The Mathematical Association of America, Washington, 2009.

Comment: I will soon try it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What often helps me is the following rather primitive intuition based on isomorphism theorems:

Suppose you have two groups/rings $A, B$. Take a normal subgroup/both sided ideal $C \subseteq A$ and consider the projection $$\pi_c:A \rightarrow A/C$$ (here it is pretty obvious what the projection does: it glues together certain elements of $A$ in a manner that allows to define operations of the classes of glued elements via represetatives of the classes. so it is something like "making the structure coarser").

Now assumee that there is a subgroup/subring $D$ of $B$ such that it is isomorphic to $A/C$ and fix some suh isomorphsim $\varphi$.

Then the composition $A\rightarrow A/C \stackrel{\varphi}\rightarrow D \subseteq B$ gives a homomorphism $A\rightarrow B$, but what the (first, I think) isomorphism theorem shows is that *every homomorphism $\psi: A\rightarrow B$ is of this form* (with $C=\mathrm{Ker} \psi$ and $D=\mathrm{Im}\psi$). So what every homomorphism does is that it makes the structure of the domain (more or less) coarser and then embeds it into the codomain.

Answer (score 3):

One way to view a homomorphism is using *group actions*. If $G$ is a group and $X$ is a set, then *an action of $G$ on the set $X$* is a map
$$\begin{align*}
G\times X&\rightarrow X\\
(g, x)&\mapsto x\cdot g
\end{align*}
$$
such that the following two conditions hold.
$$
\begin{align*}
&x\cdot 1=x\:&\forall\:x\in X\\
&x\cdot(gh)=(x\cdot g)\cdot h\:&\forall\:x\in X
\end{align*}
$$
We write$^{\dagger}$ $G\curvearrowright X$ to mean that $G$ acts on $X$. This definition might initially seem mysterious, but if you remember *[Cayley's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem)*, all this is saying is that every group acts on *something*, and another theorem of Cayley states that every group acts on a [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_graph). Other examples are Dihedral groups, which act on polygons, and the cyclic group of order $n$ acts on an $n$-gon by rotation. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Examples) has lots of examples. Group actions are *important*.

**How is this related to homomorphisms?** Well, an action $G\curvearrowright X$ corresponds to a homomorphism $G\rightarrow \operatorname{Aut}(X)$. Examples:

- The dihedral group of order $2n$, denoted $D_{n}$, is the automorphism group of an $n$-gon, and of course $D_8=\langle \alpha, \beta; \alpha\beta\alpha=\beta^{-1}, \alpha^2=1, \beta^8\rangle$ acts on a square in a natural way ($\alpha$ still flips, $\beta$ still rotates). So this action corresponds to a homomorphism $D_8\rightarrow D_4$, and it is easy to see that it is *not* injective (because the element $\beta^4$ fixes the square) but that it *is* surjective.
- The cyclic group of order $n$, $\mathbb{Z}_n$, acts on an $n$-gon by rotation. This gives an injective, non-surjective map $\mathbb{Z}_n\rightarrow D_{2n}$.
- **Cayley's theorem:** You can prove Cayley's theorem really quickly using group actions, as follows. Every group acts on itself by right multiplication:
  $$
  \begin{align*}
  G\times G&\rightarrow G\\
  (g, h)&\mapsto g\cdot h
  \end{align*}
  $$
  Hence, there exists a homomorphism $G\rightarrow S_G$ (where $S_G$ is the symmetric group on the set underlying the group $G$, so $S_G$ is the automorphism group of the *set* underlying $G$ rather than the automorphism group of the group $G$ itself). This map is injective as if $g\cdot h=1\cdot h$ then $g=1$, so the kernel is trivial. Hence, $G$ embeds into $S_G$.
- There exists a surjective homomorphism from the cyclic group of order $mn$, $\mathbb{Z}_{mn}$, to the cyclic group of order $n$, $\mathbb{Z}_n$, because both $\mathbb{Z}_{mn}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ act on the (directed) $n$-gon by rotation ("directed" means that flipping is not allowed, so the automorphism group is $\mathbb{Z}_n$ rather than $D_{2n}$). **Exercise:** Use this action to find the kernel of the surjection $\mathbb{Z}_{mn}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_n$.

---

$^{\dagger}$ This notation is the one I have come across most, but it seems that there is [no standard notation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64544/what-is-the-standard-notation-for-group-action) for an action. So perhaps I should have said "I write..."

Comment: Can you recommend me a book having in depth material on group actions. I haven't read much. +1 :)

Comment: Hmm, I think Rotman's introductory text is decent on this. I personally like the book "Graphs, groups and trees" by John Meier, which is an "advanced undergraduate" text (but which I found useful during my PhD). It is an introductory text to *geometric group theory*, which some people choose to define as "the theory of the actions of infinite groups".

Answer (score 2):

Group and ring structures (on a set $A$) is about one respectively two functions 
$A\times A\rightarrow A$.

The simple connection is that homomorphisms *preserves structures as relations*. The simplest case is graphs and graph homomorphism, where connected nodes maps on connected nodes:

$x\rightharpoonup y\implies\varphi(x)\rightharpoonup \varphi(y)$

For functions $A\times A\rightarrow A$, $(a,b)\in A^2$ is "connected" with 
$c\in A$ if and only if $a\star b=c$, and therefore $(f(a),f(b))$ is "connected" to 
$f(c)$ if $f$ is a homomorphism. That is:

$f(a)\star f(b)=f(c)=f(a\star b)$.

There is a lot of mathematical structures on sets, where homomorphisms maps "connected" elements on "connected" elements.

Answer (score 1):

Homomorphisms preserves *structure* of group/ring; i.e:

If you draw a *table* that show the "$.$" of group, then a homomorphism preserves structure on that table:

> At the row "$a$" and column "$b$" you have the element "$a.b$". Under homomorphism "$f$", at the row "$f(a)$" and column "$f(b)$" you have the element "$f(a.b)$"