# Relaxing the subgroup requirement for cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The definition I have for left cosets is as follows:

> Let $G$ be a group and let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. A left coset of $H$ in $G$ is a set of the form $gH=\{gh:h\in H\}$ for some $g\in G$.

Right cosets are defined similarly.

Is there any purpose in relaxing the requirement that $H$ be a subgroup so that $H$ only needs to be a subset of $G$? If so, what properties of cosets will still hold when this requirement is relaxed?

The only result I have found so far that still holds is $1H=H=H1$. This doesn't seem like a very useful result on its own.

It also seems that the following results won't hold when the requirement is relaxed:

1. The cardinality of the set of left cosets is equal to the that of the set of right cosets.
2. The set of left cosets forms a partition of the group $G$.
3. Lagrange's Theorem (the proof I have seen uses the the fact that the left cosets form a partition of $G$).

Comment: Since different cosets won't be disjoint, I'd say that pretty much everything that's true about cosets of a subgroup can be expected to fail. For example, everything that's based on the idea of choosing a representative element of a coset will fall apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cosets are defined by the equivalence relation: $g\sim g'\Leftrightarrow g^{-1}g'\in H$. If you consider only subsets of the group $G$, you will not get an equivalence relation, as you can check. As you surmised, you then lose your partition of $G$. So, you really need to use subgroups. Incidently, if you require $H$ to be normal in $G$ the cosets will actually be a group.

Comment: That makes sense. Can I ask if there are any textbook(s) you know of that use the equivalence relation definition? I'm using Abstract Algebra by Dummit and Foote, and occasionally Algebra by Sigler.

Comment: @Anson Hungerford uses the above equivalence relation to define cosets in his algebra textbook.

Comment: Herstein's Modern Algebra  might be another good choice

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I've already heard good things about both books!

Comment: You might want to read this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1252108/intuition-behind-quotient-groups/1253636#1253636