# Simple explanation of homomorphisms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

Could someone please explain homomorphisms to me in a simple way? I've heard the following definition:

"Let $G,H$ be groups. A mapping $\theta : G \rightarrow H$ is a homomorphism iff $\theta (xy) = \theta (x) \theta (y)$ for all $x,y \in G$"

However, I'm struggling to understand the actual meaning of this statement.

What is the geometric interpretation of $\theta (xy) = \theta (x) \theta (y)$? Does this mean that it is a linear mapping? If not, how is such a mapping different to a mapping which is not homomorphic?

Comment: Possible duplicated here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242348/intuition-on-group-homomorphisms

Comment: Very clear video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cYzp5IWqCsg

Answer (score 0):

Roughly speaking, a homomorphism is a map which respects the underlying structure of the set. In the case of a group it means the map changes a product into a product.

If the notation is additive, it changes a sum into a sum.

A well-known example will hopefully shed some light: logarithm functions are defined on the multiplicative group $\mathbf R^{*+}$, have range the additive group $\mathbf R$ and their fundamental properties are
$$\begin{cases}
\log(xy)=\log x+\log y,\\
\log 1=0.
\end{cases}$$
Hence logarithms are group homomorphisms (an even (continuous) group isomorphisms).